# Difficulty understanding the Diagonalization Lemma

Tags: logic, provability

The diagonal lemma states that:
∀Φ∃Ψ (Ψ<—>Φ(⌜Ψ⌝))

A classic use of this lemma/theorem is to prove Löb’s theorem in provability logic. In that case, the theorem is instantiated to Q<—>(Prv(Q)—>P).

Take the following argument in which the theorem is instantiated in a similar way to the use in the proof of Löb’s theorem where ‘~’ is Classical negation:

1. ∀Φ∃Ψ (Ψ<—>Φ(⌜Ψ⌝))
2. ∃Ψ (Ψ<—>(Ψ—>P))
3. ∃Ψ (Ψ<—>(Ψ—>~P))
4. Q<—>(Q—>P) Hypothesis for Existential Elim
5. ```
    R<—>(R—>~P) Hypothesis for Existential Elim
   ```
6. ```
    R & ~P  5, Prop Logic
   ```
7. ```
    Q & P    4, Prop Logic
   ```
8. ⊥            6,7 Prop Logic
9. ⊥                4,5 6-8 Existential Elim x2

What is wrong here? Is this just a re-statement of Gödel’s theorems? Clearly, both uses of ‘P’ come from a universal quantifier, so it should be ok to use it twice. Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The error is at line 2. As indicated by the Quine corners, $\Phi$ is supposed to be a statement about the Gödel number of $\Psi$, but you take it to be $\Psi\to P$, which involves the truth value of $\Psi$. There's no way to define the truth value from the Gödel number; that's Tarski's theorem on undefinability of truth.

Comment: So no logic above FOL is truth-functional? Besides, implication doesn’t need to be defined in terms of truth. That is, Q—>P can just mean that P is derivable from Q according to some set of inference rules.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 I have no idea how you decided that "no logic above FOL is truth functional". Nor do I know how you changed the meaning of $Q\to P$ to be about derivability according to some [unspecified] set of inference rules.

Comment: Q—>P has always been about the derivability of P on the assumption that Q. I misunderstood your point about Tarski. Still, it seems like I should be able to say ∃Ψ (Ψ<—>(⌜Ψ⌝—>P)), which to me seems to produce the same result. My interpretation is that either there is no predicate Φ s.t. for some Ψ, ⌜Ψ⌝—>P or there is no Φ s.t. ⌜Ψ⌝—>~P, but at least one must hold.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 In what you "should be able to say", you have a number implying a statement. That makes no sense.

Comment: So it’s not the case that for all P, P<—>⌜P⌝?

Comment: @Pdubya_24 No, a number and a statement are not equivalent.

Comment: A Gödel number is just an encoding of a string of symbols that constitute a wff into a number. The whole point is that anything that follows from the encoding follows from the formula it represents and anything following from the formula also follows from the encoding.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 As I said before, statements don't follow from numbers. Your "anything that follows from the encoding" makes no sense.